# React Component Didn't Mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got problem with my react component which renders form. Basically, when I enter countdown page, the form just doesn't work (by that I mean it doesnt act at all, I write for example 123 which is 2 min and 3 seconds and nothing happens, just nothing). But, for example, if I go on to main page and back to countdown page, it works. I have noticed that when entering this page the first time, componentWillMount works, but componentDidMount doesn't (it won't console.log the message).
Link to heroku: http://fathomless-lowlands-79063.herokuapp.com/?#/countdown?_k=mj1on6

CountdownForm.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var CountdownForm = React.createClass({
  onSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var strSeconds = this.refs.seconds.value;
    if (strSeconds.match(/^[0-9]*$/)){
      this.refs.seconds.value = '';
      this.props.onSetCountdown(parseInt(strSeconds, 10));
    }

  },
  render: function () {
    return(
      <div>
      <form ref="form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="countdown-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter time in seconds" ref="seconds" />
        <button className="button expanded">Start
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
   );
   }
  });
  module.exports = CountdownForm;
```

Countdown.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var Clock = require('Clock');
var CountdownForm = require('CountdownForm');
var Controls = require('Controls');

var Countdown = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      count: 0,
      countdownStatus: 'stopped'
     };
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.countdownStatus !== prevState.countdownStatus)
    {
      switch (this.state.countdownStatus){
          case 'started':
            this.startTimer();
            break;
            case 'stopped':
              this.setState({count: 0})
            case 'paused':
              clearInterval(this.timer)
              this.timer = undefined;
            break;
      }
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
  },
  componentWillMount: function () {
    console.log("componentWillMount");
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    console.log('componentDidUnmount');
  },
  startTimer: function () {
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        var newCount = this.state.count - 1;
        this.setState({
          count: newCount >= 0 ? newCount : 0
        });
      }, 1000);
  },
  handleSetCountdown: function (seconds){
    this.setState({
      count: seconds,
      countdownStatus: 'started'
    });
  },
  handleStatusChange: function (newStatus) {
    this.setState({
      countdownStatus: newStatus
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    var {count, countdownStatus} = this.state;
    var renderControlArea = () => {
      if (countdownStatus !== 'stopped') {
      return <Controls countdownStatus={countdownStatus} onStatusChange={this.handleStatusChange} />
      } else {
        return <CountdownForm onSetCountdown={this.handleSetCountdown} />
      }

    };
    return(
    <div>
      <Clock totalSeconds={count} />
      {renderControlArea()}
    </div>
  );
}
});
module.exports = Countdown;
```

Comment: Where piece of code is not working? I don't see componentWillMount or componentDidMount

Comment: Saying something "doesn't work" without providing any type of error is not advisable.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't realized i didnt pushed the changes to github, only to heroku. By doesnt work I mean I got a form and after clicking start button or clicking enter it should send form and function onSubmit should be called, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Main issue was error: "Uncaught Error: Stateless function components cannot have refs.
    at invariant" . The problem was with stateless components, so that's why I instead of using arrow functions in Main.jsx and Nav.jsx, I used the React.createClass({}).